# Amazon API gateway ignores set-cookie

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, setcookie

I am trying to set session cookie from a Lambda API Gateway integration to the client but it will never send the `Set-Cookie` header.

I don't see the `Set-Cookie` in the API Gateway logs neither.

Here is an example of the `Set-Cookie` header hard-coded in the Integration Response when `HTTP Status` is `200`

[image]

The `Set-Cookie` is not sent but the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header is sent to the client

---

**UPDATE 23-06**

---

It appears that using the Mapping template in the Integration Response is working but setting it in the Header Mapping doesn't.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/) of any help at all?

Comment: I tried this: It works when I hard-code the cookie value, but doesn't when I use `integration.response.header.Cookie`. I pass the `Cookie` in the response headers from my Lambda